# char, const char char* array issues for MQTT client.publish

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char, c-strings

I am using Arduino IDE to program an ESP8266, which is connected to a number of sensors. The end goal is to publish the sensor data via MQTT.

I have an array with sensor names:

```
const char* sensorIDArray[] = { // Used for the MQTT string
  "DS18B20_1",
  "DS18B20_2",
  "DS18B20_3",
  "DHT22_t",
  "DHT22_h",
  "Hygrometer_1",
  "Hygrometer_1",
  "Hygrometer_1",
  "Hygrometer_1",
  "Battery"
};
```

I have another array which is populated with some sensor readings:

```
float readingsArray[10]; //Saving the last measurement
/* Array element reminder:
 *
 * readingsArray[0] = DS18B20_1
 * readingsArray[1] = DS18B20_2
 * readingsArray[2] = DS18B20_3
 * readingsArray[3] = DHT22_t
 * readingsArray[4] = DHT22_h
 * readingsArray[5] = Hygrometer_1
 * readingsArray[6] = Hygrometer_2
 * readingsArray[7] = Hygrometer_3
 * readingsArray[8] = Hygrometer_4
 * readingsArray[9] = Battery
 */
```

I am then trying to send the reading to a MQTT client by looping through each element of the array:

```
char readingVal;
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    dtostrf(readingsArray[i], 7, 2, readingVal); //convert float to string
    char* topic = "ESPlant/" + sensorIDArray[i]; //concatenate MQTT topic
    client.publish(topic, readingVal);  //publish MQTT topic and sensor reading
    delay(10); //delay to ease burden on MQTT server.
}
```

I am new to C++ and Arduino in general. I am very confused by `char`, `char*` and arrays of both, despite many hours of googling. The `client.publish` is limited to a String only (!!!) for the argument `readingVal` above. The error message is:

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Why are you not using the Arduino [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/) class? Why is `readingVal` of type `char`, when you are going to store a _string_ in it? How do you expect `char* topic = "ESPlant/" + sensorIDArray[i]` to work?

Comment: `char* topic = "ESPlant/" + sensorIDArray[i];` -- This does not do concatenation in C++.  To be honest with you, your issue has nothing to do with MQTT, Arduino, or anything else *except*, simple, basic, C++ that you will find in any textbook.

Comment: I started going down the route of String class but it seemed to be getting more complicated, can you give an example? I expect the topic to be a concatenation of for example ESPlant/ and DS18B20_1 for location 0. So the whole topic will read: ESPlant/DS18B20_1

Comment: PaulMkenzie, many thank for your comment. I am not alone in finding this site very unwelcoming. Please can someone assist me with something constructive? Thanks.

Comment: @EdwardHammock C++ is not JavaScript or Python.  You have two `char` pointers, and you do not concatenate those using `+`.  Seems as if you're trying to write C++ by using other computer languages as a guide.  That never works.  The proper way to concatenate strings is to either use a string class to represent strings that has overloaded operator `+`, or if using string literals and char arrays, use `strcat`.  But this should be covered in *any* good C++ tutorial, book, or website.

Comment: @EdwardHammock [This shows the Arduino String class has this feature](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/operators/concatenation/).  The issue is that using `char*` and arrays, you get absolutely no help in concatenation by using `+`.  All you wind up doing is adding two pointer values.  Arrays and pointers are dumb -- they don't do what you think is being done if you're using `+`.  Use string *classes*, not low-level constructs such as pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As others have hinted at in the comments, it could not hurt to read a few Arduino tutorials.  If you are not familiar with c "strings" you should definitely try to steer clear of them.

The [String](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples#strings) class was really created for those who don't really know c/c++.  As you seem to know the Arduino language really is just c++, but they try to simplify things for those not familiar with it.

dtostrf() is a pretty complex function if you are not up on c/c++.  For example the last parameter is supposed to be a "buffer", big enough to hold the result of the conversion. In your example you are passing a pointer with no memory allocated to it at all.  You can avoid this using String.

String allows you do just to something like the following (from the tutorial [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator))

```
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0); 
String stringOne = "Sensor value: ";
String stringThree = stringOne + sensorValue;
Serial.println(stringThree);
```

When you reach a point that you need to pass a String to a function expecting a char* (c/c++ string),  you can do something like this.

```
someFunctionNeedingACharArray(stringOne.c_str());
```

The c_str() method converts the String to a c/c++ style char* "string"

Hope this helps.